# How can I combine the values of multiple columns, all in different tables, into a single column in a view?

Tags: sql, mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I am working with multiple tables in a data vault in Snowflake. All the data is to do with business journeys for a company; air, rail, car rental, hotel stays. I need to create views in the presentation layer that will hold data in a star schema. All the data in the presentation layer will be coming from the data vault.

The dimension table in the presentation layer that I need to make is as follows:

travel skey,
mode of transport,
company(combines hotel chain, car company, airline)
departure location (combines air departure airport and rail origin station),
arrival location (combines air destination airport, rail destination station, hotel city),
class (combines airline class, rail class),
hotel property name,
arrival region

As you can see, to create this view, I have to get columns from multiple tables and merge them into one column, and do this for multiple columns in the presentation layer. Here's a simplified example of what I would like to do:

Table 1
Hotel chain = the berkeley

Table 2
Car company = Hertz

Table 3
Airline = American Airlines

NEW table in the presentation layer:
Company = the berkeley, Hertz, American Airlines

I have tried a UNION statement as follows (replace generic table names with the ones i have mentioned):

```
CREATE VIEW CombinedCompanyView AS
SELECT car_company AS company FROM BookingDetails
UNION ALL
SELECT hotel_company AS company FROM BookingDetails;
```

but the size of this statement is really confusing me and I dont know if I am doing it correctly. I think it wont work because the columns im trying to join are all coming from different tables

Answer (score 0):

The UNION statement you provided will not work because the columns you are trying to join are all coming from different tables. To join the columns of multiple tables you will need to use a JOIN statement. A JOIN statement allows you to combine rows from two or more tables based on a common value.

In case, you need to combine rows from BookingDetails, CarDetails and HotelDetails tables based on the Key column value.

Like that;

```
CREATE VIEW CombinedCompanyView AS
SELECT Key, Company
FROM BookingDetails
JOIN CarDetails ON BookingDetails.Key = CarDetails.Key
JOIN HotelDetails ON BookingDetails.Key = HotelDetails.Key;
```

Use the code carefully. know more
This JOIN statement will combine rows from the BookingDetails, CarDetails, and HotelDetails tables based on the value of the Key column. It will then return a new table with Key and Company columns.

The Company column in the new table will contain the company for the trip. If the trip was a flight, the Company column will contain the name of the airline. If the trip was a car rental, the Company column will contain the name of the car rental company. If the trip was a hotel stay, the Company column will contain the name of the hotel chain.